# Can I use a Managed Package Visualforce page in Utility bar?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, managed-package, utility-bar

I created a new Lightning application in which I added some utility items.I also want to add a Visualforce page in the Utility bar but the page is from a Managed package.
Is it even possible?
Is there any way we could find the "Lightning ready Visualforce Pages" in Salesforce org?